# PHP: Undefined offset while using explode a scandir

Tags: php, undefined, offset, explode, scandir

```
<?php
$dir = "user/jas527/uploads/";
$a = scandir($dir);
for($i=2;$i<$a;$i++){
print_r(explode('.',$a[$i]));
}
?>
```

i'm trying to explode file names of a directory.
but i got a error.

Comment: please share the error with us ...

Comment: No directories exist in the folder or a is null so scandir couldn't open the directory. As advice start learning how to debug code, it will help you in the long run.

Comment: `scandir` returns an **array** of files and directories. You need the length of the array for the for-loop. You can get that with `count()`. I'll explain that in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make correction like this

```
   for($i=2; $i<count($a); $i++){
```

Comment: `scandir` returns array, so you have to use `count` function  count all elements in an array

Answer (score 1):

use foreach instead of for, you do not know how many files are in there, and its so simple to use foreach .

```
foreach($a as $file){
    print_r(explode('.',$file));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scandir` returns an **array** of files and directories from the directory ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)). You need the length of the array for the for-loop. You can get this with `count()`.

[image: scandir]

[image: count]

Change your for-loop to

```
<?php
$dir = "user/jas527/uploads/";
$a = scandir($dir);
// for($i=2;$i<$a;$i++){
for($i=2; $i<count($a); $i++){
    print_r(explode('.',$a[$i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

scandir returns an array of files and directories from the directory.SO you have to get total number of elemeny.You forget `count` to get total number of element in `array`

```
for($i=2;$i<count($a);$i++){
```

Read [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)